# A form timer in php

Tags: php, datetime

I want a form to be submitted atleast 15 seconds after the page has loaded (because thats how long it takes on average for the form to be filled in).

I know I can do something like $time_page_loaded = time() at the top;

```
if (time() < $time_page_loaded + 15)
{
  // show reCaptcha
}
else
{
  // submit to database
}
```

Is this correct? Also when you re-factor this into a function how would you make it?

Comment: You can't do that with PHP. Ohh! Unless of course, this is written in a process page loaded when the form is submitted? Anyway, why not use jquery for that? Or, why not forget about it? If the data is OK, why bother?

Comment: This is one example of why we need down votes on comments. i love the last part *Why Bother*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect the time-to-submission on the server, you'd have to store the original time the form was sent to the user somewhere. In a session variable (good), or in a hidden form field (bad, unless you encrypt/heavily obfuscate the value), etc... When the form's submitted, you take the current time, compare it to that stored value, then decided on showing the captcha or not.

However, since the form HAS been submitted, and it was done in less than the cutoff time, you'd have to rebuild the entire form (including the extra captcha) stuff and show it to the user again - if the form allows file uploads, you'd be forcing the user to upload the file at least twice.

Implementing this client-side in javascript would be a bit more userfriendly (as long as you had server-side handling as well). Store the current time in a javascript variable when the page is loaded. Put an "onsubmit" handler onto the form. When the form's submitted, the handler fires, compares times, and either allows the form submission to proceed, or aborts the submission and inserts the recaptcha sections into the form.

Comment: So I should implement both right? In case the user doesn't have javascript enabled.

Comment: Yes, unless you're working in a closed/guaranteed environment, you should never depend on the user for anything - always have server-side validation.

Answer (score 2):

you would be able to use cookies for this bit as this is a security measure i would advise you use sessions.

sessions is a way to store small amounts of content within a file on your server that is only valid with a cookie hash.

at the very beginning of your script you need to put the following command:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

When the page loads you can assign a timestamps to the session, and upon submission you can calculate the time taken with the above:

```
if (time() < $_SESSION["time_page_loaded"] + 15)
{
    // Captcha
}
```

Comment: You could use `http-only` cookies. When you also encrypt=>http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=606? them I think you are pretty safe. But this is also a good solution :P.

Answer (score -1):

With the approach you are discussing you would need to put a `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo time(); ?>" />` (or use a session variable) in your page and compare that value to the current output of the `time()` function and take action from there.  The boilerplate code you wrote above would work fine.

If I may though, I'm not sure this is a very nice user experience you are providing.  The user doesn't know until after the fact (IE submitting the form) that he has done something 'wrong.'  Using jQuery you could provide a fairly nice experience:

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/

Comment: Obviously he is using Captcha for security against bots, and a bot is able to modify any values within a form. your answer defies the point of captcha int he first place.

Answer (score -2):

You should put a hidden input field with the page loaded time (generated by PHP) and when the form is submitted, compare the submit time against the hidden input value

BUT this is not secure at all. You should use something like javascript in order to do that

Comment: Obviously he is using Captcha for security against bots, and a bot is able to modify any values within a form. your answer defies the point of captcha int he first place.

Comment: I think the best spambots are smart enough to wait 15 seconds or so before they post, but I could be wrong about that!

Comment: I've seen spam bots that spider the form once, then come back hours/days later to hammer the hell out of it. Obviously including a one-time key into the form prevents that, but a simple timer won't prevent the smart ones from doing much of anything.

Comment: +1 @marc B, it won't stop them, possible slow them down a little.